# Selenium web driver package library

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-rcp

I'm newbie in Selenium web driver

When i start writing this error occur in 1st line

> " package is not accessible".

Please help.

[image]

Comment: If you are new to Selenium and Java, i would suggest create a maven project and add selenium as a dependency. It would be much easier. Or else just expand the libraries in the eclipse and check if you can see the selenium jars.

Comment: @Soha Mir, Welcome to StackOverflow. your pictures are not uploaded. please re-upload them.

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh "i need atleast 10 reputation to post an image" :'( this message pop up when em inserting an image

Comment: @Soha Mir, Upvoted. Whenever you reached please upload images and also you can upload it on some other websites and we could editing for you.

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh please check

Comment: @Soha Mir, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Download selenium jars from here

https://download.jar-download.com/cache_jars/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.0/jar_files.zip

1. Right-click your project.
2. Click Properties.
3. In the left pane, click on Java Build Path.
4. On the Libraries tab, click Add External JARs.
5. Select all of the .jar files you downloaded from the above link.
6. Click Apply and close.